# How can I actually see realtime users currently on my website on Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

So recently I started using Google Analytics 4 since Universal Analytics now has en end-of-life date.

I am having a hard time seeing the users that are currently on my website. In Univeral Analytics, it looked like this:
[image]

You can clearly see there are 3 users currently active on the site. You can also clearly see what page they are visiting.

Google Analytics 4 however, decided to redefine the word 'realtime'. As far as I know, they now consider every user that has triggered a page view event in the last 30 minutes to be a current active user. This is how it currently looks in GA4:

[image]

I do not know however, if that user has already left or if they are still on the site. I do now know what page they are visiting. I don't really care about the users that have triggered a page-view event in the last 30 minutes. I want to know 'realtime' how many users are currently on my website and what page they are visiting (like in UA).

Is that possible in GA4? Maybe I am overlooking something or there is a different report that I am not aware of?